# cant reach a registered instance from eureka

Tags: node.js, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have created a nodejs application that registers itself with a eureka service.
When I go to `localhost:8761` I can see the registered instance.
but when I send a request to `localhost:8761/refdata`, I am unable to get the details from the registered nodejs application.
But when I make a request to `localhost:3000/refdata` , which is the actual service, I get the response.
I am using eureka-js-client to register with the eureka server.

```
const Eureka = require('eureka-js-client').Eureka

const client = new Eureka({
    instance:{
        app: 'refdataservice',
    hostName: 'localhost',
    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
    port: {
        '$': 3000,
        '@enabled': 'true',
      },
    vipAddress: 'metallica.refdata.service.com',
    statusPageUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/info',
    dataCenterInfo: {
        '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
          name: 'MyOwn',
    }
    },
    eureka: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8761,
        servicePath: '/eureka/apps/'
    }
})
```

Am I using the wrong url to send the request ?
I have also tried `localhost:8761/refdataservice/refdata`

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 0):

Eureka is just a **registry for discovering services** and is **NOT a proxy** for your request. So any URLs that you wrote will not work.

What you need is Eureka-enabled http client or gateway.

If you setup Spring Cloud Zuul as a gateway, it will forward your request based on the information that exists in Eureka.

If you use any Http client that is Eureka-enabled like Spring Cloud Feign, LoadBalanced RestTemplate, it will send http request just with service name wihtout specifying hostname and port,

Or you can implement it by yourself. Fetching server list from Eureka server and choose and use one of them.